# Является ли строка панграммой?

Tags: python

Требуется проверить, является ли строка панграммой, т.е если в строке все буквы алфавита.

И я ее решил таким образом:

```
def is_pangram(s):
    return set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') == set(s.lower().replace(' ', ''))

text = input()

print(is_pangram(text))
```

Но нашел схожее решение:

```
def is_pangram(s):
    return not set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') - set(s.lower())

text = input()

print(is_pangram(text))
```

Не могу понять 2х вещей:

1. почему вычитая одно множество из другого куда-то девается знак пробела
2. почему добавляя логический оператор not функция возвращает булево значение

Comment: Ещё тут можно не перечислять "вручную" все буквы, а использовать `from string import ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> почему вычитая одно множество из другого куда-то девается знак пробела?

Когда мы вычитаем множество `B` из `A` в результирующем множестве остаются только те элементы из множества `A`, которые не встречаются в множестве `B`.

В множества `A` символ пробела отсутствует, поэтому он не может быть в результате.

---

> почему добавляя логический оператор not функция возвращает булево значение?

```
In [163]: not set()
Out[163]: True
```

интерпретируется как:

```
In [165]: not bool(set())
Out[165]: False
```

именно это и происходит при проверке результата

PS [здесь](https://snarky.ca/unravelling-not-in-python/) можно подробнее прочитать о том как работает `not <expression>` в `Python` и как это реализовано в исходном коде `Python`